# Feed Prometheus from a Kafka bridge

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus

We try to feed metrics from worldwide distributed devices into Prometheus.
To decouple the devices from the services (to avoid too many direct communications), there is a message broker and a Kafka bridge.

```
+----------------------------------+
|   Device 1                       |
| +---------------+                |
| | Application I |--+             |
| +---------------+   \            |
|                      |           |
| +----------------+   |  +------+ |              +------+     +----------+       +--------------+
| | Application II |---+->| MQTT |-|---metrics--->| MQTT |---->|  Kafka   |------>| Prometheus   |
| +----------------+   |  +------+ |              +------+     +----------+       +--------------+
|                      |           |
| +-----------------+  /           |
| | Application III |-+            |
| +-----------------+              |
+----------------------------------+
```

We struggle to figure out how to feed Prometheus from the Kafka bridge more or less directly. We could - of course - instantiate translation services per Application (Service) on each device, but this feels being overkill.

We didn't find any suggestion on https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exporters/ - but I think we ask the wrong questions.

Our first application is a collectd to measure some common system metrics. This is a reasonable data source since everyone knows what should be seen in Prometheus then.

The communication

```
+------+                +------+     +----------+
| MQTT |----Internet--->| MQTT |---->|  Kafka   |
+------+                +------+     +----------+
```

cannot reasonable opened up for particular messages, since each message shall receive Kafka.

Comment: The question is maybe sibling to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61825022/how-to-export-data-from-kafka-to-prometheus or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50517152/report-prometheus-metrics-via-kafka.

Comment: Prometheus pulls its data from exporters. The exporters don't push, they expose metrics at an HTTP endpoint. JMX exporter for Kafka will export Kafka's metrics, and so, I think what you need is a custom Prometheus exporter that pulls data from Kafka and translates your application metrics into something Prometheus understands.

Answer (score 0):

There is only a [remote write](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/integrations/#remote-endpoints-and-storage) integration for Kafka **from** Prometheus.

If you intend to collect metrics from external resources, you wouldn't write to Kafka at all, rather add some exporter (ex. [collectd exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/collectd_exporter)) to the applications themselves, then setup scrape targets against them since Prometheus is *pull-based*.

If you really wanted to use Kafka, you would need to **write a consumer** first, then use PushGateway to *push data*; there is nothing provided by Prometheus project for this, that I am aware of. Or you can basically rewrite (or pay Confluent for) that Kafka Connect project [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61825022/how-to-export-data-from-kafka-to-prometheus).

---

One alternative, install a StatsD server as a relay - https://github.com/prometheus/statsd_exporter#relaying-from-statsd

Push to that, rather than Kafka. (Or again, consume from Kafka, and push to the statsd server)

Comment: Since the collectd (and other applications) are „remote“ it is not reasonable to write directly from collectd into Prometheus.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Again, Prometheus would be **pulling** collectd-exporter

Comment: No, prometheus cannot pull the collectd-exporter. This is prohibited.

Comment: By who / why? What about statsd? Regardless, like I said, there's nothing that can push to Prometheus except for PushGateway. Or you need a different exporter. For example, there's this project I found on Github. https://github.com/bendikwa/mqtt_exporter

Comment: Prohibition is enforced by authentication architecture.
We check the statsd relay as well as the Confluent Kafka Connect project and an own service. I finally tried to understand the limitations around and got that the transport layer is not optimized for prometheus architecture.

Comment: Cortex has a push endpoint that might work better (that's what we run), but I do think InfluxDB or TimescaleDB might be better as there's better Kafka tooling that can be used with those